# OpenVPN CCD file extensions

Tags: windows, openvpn

I've setup an OpenVPN server on Windows, all is working fine. I want to have my OpenVPN clients connect with a predetermined IP address. With reading/research I understand this is pushed out via a file in the CCD folder on the server.

My question is rather simple: In the OpenVPN/Config/CCD directory, what is the file extension for the "file" that gets created. No tutorial specifies.

user1.??
user2.??

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There is no file extension, the filename should simply match the name from the  *Common Name* (CN) in the certificate presented by the client.

Ie, if the CN is `foo`, the filename is `foo`.

See the CCD section in the [manual](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage):

> **--client-config-dir dir**
>   Specify a directory **dir** for custom client config files. After a connecting client has been authenticated,
>   OpenVPN will look in this directory for a file having the same name as
>   the client's X509 common name. If a matching file exists, it will be
>   opened and parsed for client-specific configuration options. If no
>   matching file is found, OpenVPN will instead try to open and parse a
>   default file called "DEFAULT", which may be provided but is not
>   required. Note that the configuration files must be readable by the
>   OpenVPN process after it has dropped it's root privileges.
>
> This file
>   can specify a fixed IP address for a given client using
>   **--ifconfig-push**, as well as fixed subnets owned by the client using **--iroute**.
>
> One of the useful properties of this option is that it allows client
>   configuration files to be conveniently created, edited, or removed
>   while the server is live, without needing to restart the server.
>
> The following options are legal in a client-specific context: **--push**,
>   **--push-reset**, **--push-remove**, **--iroute**, **--ifconfig-push**, and **--config**.

Comment: I've created a no-file extension file in CCD, named it the same as the CN of the client connecting, in this I have ifconfig-push 192.168.100.100 (which is the address I want it to have on my VPN's 192.168.100.0/24 network), I then restart the service and check ipconfig and still connects with it's DHCP lease of 192.168.100.2 :S

Comment: @UniqueTurbo When you say "DHCP lease" do you mean that you've arranged to literally use the DHCP protocol over an L2 tunnel (ie tap) or just the normal OpenVPN address assignment (ie based on `server` / `ifconfig-pool`, `ifconfig-push`)?

Comment: I am finding this works until the service is restarted and then the static leases disappear and all IP addresses go back to being a random number from the pool. :(